# FOSElasticaBundle disturbs lifecyle events

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, fosuserbundle, foselasticabundle

I have installed FOSElasticaBundle to handle search and used the following configuration:

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
    indexes:
        search:
            client: default
            types:
                post:
                    mappings:
                        postTitle: ~
                        postContent: ~
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: Shop\Bundle\ManagementBundle\Entity\Post
                        provider: ~
                        listener: ~            
                        finder: ~
```

Search is working fine, but when I try to login a user, he is succesfully logged in but I get a redirection to  `login_check` route with the following error:

> ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   FOS\ElasticaBundle\Doctrine\Listener::postUpdate() must be an instance
>   of Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs, instance of
>   Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\community\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ContainerAwareEventManager.php
>   on line 63 and defined in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\community\vendor\friendsofsymfony\elastica-bundle\Doctrine\Listener.php
>   line 111

If I am not wrong, the `login_check` path is updating the record of the user (precisely the last_login_date field in `user` table) which triggers the `postUpdate()` lifecycle event. But I can't resolve the issue. Yout help is appreciated.

**PS:** I am using FOSUserBundle for users storage in database.

**Edit:**  the above issue happens for other entities persistence lifecycle events (preRemove()...) as well.